# Python ModuleNotFoundError - x86cpu

Tags: python, pip

whenever I try to run a script i have on my computer via command prompt, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\andrew.rudner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage exec(line)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\andrew.rudner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\despatch\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from .despatch import set_optimal, set_cpu_type # noqa
File "C:\Users\andrew.rudner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\despatch\despatch.py", line 6, in <module>
from x86cpu import info
File "C:\Users\andrew.rudner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\x86cpu\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .cpuinfo import info, cpuid, has_cpuid
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x86cpu.cpuinfo'
```

Basically saying I dont have the module 'x86cpu.cpuinfo'. I tried reinstalling the library with the command -m pip install x86cpu, and get the message "Requirement already satisfied: x86cpu in c:\users\andrew.rudner\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.4)". Despite it saying that its already installed, the module not found error message doesnt go away. Any insight as to how to solve the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error comes _from within_ that module, so I'd say that the module is broken

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're having issues with the module x86cpu so install it.

```
pip install x86cpu
```

and if it is already installed then reinstall it.

```
pip uninstall x86cpu
```

then

```
pip install x86cpu
```

Comment: I am trying to follow up, was your issue solved already?